# Best way for running multiple task asynchronously c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Which is the best way for running multiple Task asynchronously having the best perfomance?

In my case i have to read multiple folders retrieving their size and files count.

I've noticed that after a while the process slows down.

I would like to know if this is the best way for handling this long operations waiting for them or if there's a better way.

Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            DbManager dbManager = new DbManager();
            DataTable _dtDirectoriesToWork = dbManager.SelectDirectoriesToCount();

            var _tasks = new List<Task<ReadDataResults>>();

            foreach (DataRow _Directory in _dtDirectoriesToWork.Rows)
            {
                ReadArchiveRunner _RunnerArchive =
                    new ReadArchiveRunner(_Directory["PathDirectory"].ToString(), _Directory["ID"].ToString());

                _RunnerArchive.ProcessReadPath();

                _tasks.Add(_RunnerArchive.ReadTask);
            }

            Task.WaitAll(_tasks.ToArray());

            //Operations after finished


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {               

        }

    }
```

ReadArchiveRunner Class:

```
class ReadArchiveRunner
{
    DbManager _SqlDbman = new DbManager();
    MailManager _Mailman = new MailManager();
    LogManager _Logman = new LogManager();


    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpace(string lpRootPathName,
        out uint lpSectorsPerCluster,
        out uint lpBytesPerSector,
        out uint lpNumberOfFreeClusters,
        out uint lpTotalNumberOfClusters);

    private uint _lpSectorsPerCluster;
    private uint _lpBytesPerSector;
    private uint _lpNumberOfFreeClusters;
    private uint _lpTotalNumberOfClusters;

    public Task<ReadDataResults> ReadTask { get; set; }
    private string DirecotryToScan { get; set; }
    private string IDDirecotryToScan { get; set; }

    string _Error = null;

    public void ProcessReadPath()
    {
        ReadTask = Task.Run(() => ReadPath());
    }

    public ReadArchiveRunner(string Directory, string IDDirectory)
    {
        DirecotryToScan = Directory;
        IDDirecotryToScan = IDDirectory;
    }

    private ReadDataResults ReadPath()
    {
        try
        {
            Int64 sizeondisk = 0;
            uint _ClusterDimensions = 0;

            DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(DirecotryToScan);
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();


            sw.Start();
            Int64 ttl = 0;
            Int32 fileCount = 0;

            GetDiskFreeSpace(DirecotryToScan, out _lpSectorsPerCluster, out _lpBytesPerSector, out _lpNumberOfFreeClusters, out _lpTotalNumberOfClusters);

            _ClusterDimensions = _lpSectorsPerCluster * _lpBytesPerSector;

            IEnumerable<FileInfo> _dirFileInfo = DirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (FileInfo fi in _dirFileInfo)
            {
                if (!fi.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
                {
                    ttl += fi.Length;
                    sizeondisk += _ClusterDimensions * ((fi.Length + _ClusterDimensions - 1) / _ClusterDimensions);
                    fileCount++;
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();

            string resultGbDimensioni = FormatBytes(ttl);
            string resultGbDimensioniSuDisco = FormatBytes(sizeondisk);

            ReadDataResults _RecordResult = new ReadDataResults
            {
                IDDirectory = IDDirecotryToScan,
                TempoTotale = FormatMilliseconds(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds),
                TotaleFiles = fileCount,
                TotaleDimensione = ttl,
                TotaleDimensioneSuDisco = sizeondisk,
                TotaleDimensioneFormatted = resultGbDimensioni,
                TotaleDimensioneSuDiscoFormatted = resultGbDimensioniSuDisco
            };

            Console.WriteLine(DirecotryToScan +
                "\Tempo Totale: " + _RecordResult.TempoTotale +
                "\nTotale Dimensione: " + _RecordResult.TotaleDimensione + " " + _RecordResult.TotaleDimensioneFormatted +
                "\nTempo Dimensione Su Disco: " + _RecordResult.TotaleDimensioneSuDisco + " " + _RecordResult.TotaleDimensioneSuDiscoFormatted +
                "\nTotale Files: " + _RecordResult.TotaleFiles + "\n");

            _SqlDbman.InsertRecordReadData(_RecordResult, out _Error);               


            return _RecordResult;
        }
        catch (Exception Exc)
        {
            string _ErrorMessage = DirecotryToScan +
                "\n " + Exc.Message;

            Console.WriteLine(_ErrorMessage);
            _Logman.WriteToLog(_ErrorMessage);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

    private string FormatMilliseconds(long MilliSeconds)
    {
        TimeSpan _t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(MilliSeconds);
        string _TimeFormatted = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s:{3:D3}ms",
                                _t.Hours,
                                _t.Minutes,
                                _t.Seconds,
                                _t.Milliseconds);
        return _TimeFormatted;
    }

    private string FormatBytes(long bytes)
    {
        string[] Suffix = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
        int i;
        double dblSByte = bytes;
        for (i = 0; i < Suffix.Length && bytes >= 1024; i++, bytes /= 1024)
        {
            dblSByte = bytes / 1024.0;
        }

        return String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", dblSByte, Suffix[i]);
    }



}
```

Comment: if this is working code, consider posting on [https://codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead, or define "best way": if it is unstable because of race conditions and the like, isolate the malfunction first. you may want to limit the total number of concurrent tasks running at a time. CPU and I/O resources are limited, unbounded parallelity does not necessarily mean a job gets done faster.

Comment: Please identify your problem and leave only code which is required to show the problem. Should 1000 people read dozens of lines of code and how you calculate and display free disk space? Is it related to your problem or problem is just any lengthy operation which should be run in parallel?

Comment: the problem is that when i put 100 paths for reading process with 100 async tasks. the reading process goes slowly. I would like to know for a scenario like this, which colud be a better approach for getting a faster execution time

Comment: Maybe it's because your hard drive / SSD has limited throughput? ;-)

Comment: i think is not related to disk's limits. i only want to know if is this a correct way to start a large amount of long tasks getting the best performance

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's faster to call an OS level index for the file system info you want? Traversing folders yourself will take longer. Just list the entire directory and then query those paths.

Comment: `Task.WaitAll(_tasks.ToArray());` is synchronous wait. For asyncchronous wait use `await Task.WhenAll(_tasks.ToArray());`

Comment: i need the WaitAll Method Because i have to read each result of each task.

I only would like to know if long tasks becomes slowly during running operations and how to handle this.